# Jetpack Infinite Scroll - Add more than 7 posts each time?

Tags: ajax, plugin-jetpack

By default, everytime the infinite scroll loads some more posts, it loads 7 posts. Is there a way to load more posts than just 7 each time?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to make a custom query with a posts_per_page argument to the desired number of posts.

Comment: You don't use a custom query for that, you can just add the posts_per_page argument to the add_theme_support call. Docs here: http://jetpack.me/support/infinite-scroll/

Comment: Wow, I read this doc about 5 times, and I never saw that. #Blind
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I presume your blog is set to show at most 7 posts per page.  Try going to Settings>Reading and adjust the number for posts per page, which is labeled: "*Blog pages show at most*"

Comment: No the inifinite loader does not load the posts according to the value that was set in Settings->Reading, unless it is set to "click", wich is not my case :/

Comment: Really? I was under the impression that Infinite Scroll basically works by finding the "next" link, visiting that page and scraping the posts there.  If so, this would always respect the posts per page parameter since it isn't querying the DB via ajax, it is simply looking at what the next page would've been.  But maybe something else is happening in Jetpack that I'm not aware of.